# Array in serializer with multiple serializer rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, json

I am getting array after processing.

```
gem 'active_model_serializers'
```

Now i want to use `serializer` to send data in json format.

But when i called the serializer, it'll not getting object because of **Array**.

Controller -

```
def index
  question = user.questions.available 
  answer = user.where(:answer => params[:ans])
  render :json => {:qust => question, :each_serializer => QuestionSerializer,
                   :ans => answer, :each_serializer => AnswerSerializer}
end
```

question_serializer.rb

```
class QuestionSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :question, :type
end
```

answer_serializer.rb

```
class AnswerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :answer, :date

  def date
   object.date = "..."
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what's coming out of this because it's not clear what your problem is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
render json: {
  qust: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(question, each_serializer: QuestionSerializer),
  ans: ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new(answer, each_serializer: AnswerSerializer),
}
```

Side remarks:

- beware of your naming, use plural when you work with collections.
- `answer = user.where(:answer => params[:ans])` looks bad

Comment: Syntax has been updated from `ActiveModel::ArraySerializer.new` to `ActiveModel::Serializer::CollectionSerializer.new` - see https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/issues/1809

Comment: hey.. using this method current_user in not accessible in serializer

Comment: @HardikGondaliya add `scope: current_user` and use `scope` in your serializer

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

```
options        = {each_serializer: QuestionSerializer}
user_questions = user.questions.available 
questions      = ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(user_questions, options)

render json: {
   qust: questions.as_json
}
```